# Node.js - basename in filter

Tags: node.js, express

I found some code related to fs, and path module of Node.js.

But, I could not understand what '(file !== basename)' in filter means.
Please check example code written below.

```
const fs = require('fs')
const path = require('path')
const basename = path.basename(__filename)

... Some Code

const modelFiles = fs
    .readdirSync(path.join(__dirname, '../../../module/', value.model))
    .filter(file => {
        return (file.indexOf('.') !== 0) && (file !== basename) && (file.slice(-3) === '.js')
    })
```

What I searched through Google is...
basename() returns file name in path. If so, what is meaning of a 'file name is not equal to basename (file !== basename)'? Is file name always same as basename?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Not exactly: _"Although Windows usually treats file names, including file extensions, in a case-insensitive manner, this function does not. For example, C:\\foo.html and C:\\foo.HTML refer to the same file, but basename treats the extension as a case-sensitive string"_ And __filename is a global variable which returns the filename of the code which is executed. It gives the absolute path of the code filename..

Comment: This filter func basically returns all files except the __filename-file itself and the one's not having a .js extension..